# hide show divs jquery with freewall.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the freewall jquery plugin ( http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/ )
All working fine.

Now I would like to add an option where people can select to show or hide a div.
Also working fine.

Example:
http://www.surveydesigners.com/freewall/

If you click on the options in the "Question 1"
you will see how it works.

However it is not showing the layout I normally get when I leave my hide show divs option out (the first js script below).

The reason is probably because I want todo wall.refresh() before the freewall is created. I changed the orders of this but it doesn't help.

I assume it is something small but can't get it working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

                $('#id_radio1').click(function () {
                    $('#div2').hide('fast');
                    $('#div1').show('fast');
                });
                $('#id_radio2').click(function () {
                    $('#div1').show('slow');
                    $('#div2').show('fast');
                });
                $('#id_radio3').click(function () {
                    $('#div1').hide('fast');
                    $('#div2').hide('fast');
                });     

                wall.refresh();                                     
        }); 
    </script>           

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var colour = [
            "rgb(142, 68, 173)",
            "rgb(243, 156, 18)",
            "rgb(135, 0, 0)",
            "rgb(211, 84, 0)",
            "rgb(0, 106, 63)",
            "rgb(192, 57, 43)",
            "rgb(39, 174, 96)",
            "rgb(41, 128, 185)"
        ];

        $(".brick").each(function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor =  colour[colour.length * Math.random() << 0];
        });

        $(function() {
            var wall = new freewall("#freewall");

            wall.reset({
                selector: '.brick',
                animate: true,
                cellW: 160,
                cellH: 160,
                onResize: function() {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }
            }); 
            wall.addCustomEvent('onBlockLoad', function(setting){
                console.log(setting);
            });

            wall.fitWidth();

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: i have this error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: wall is not defined`

Comment: I think if you move the code of first `$(function (){` function after `wall.fitWidth();` all work

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. The Uncaught ReferenceError is now gone but the functions for the show hide divs are not working.

Comment: I have setup a JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/surveydesigners/upjecfyv/